# String to template type via Object.factory(...)

Tags: d

Can a string be converted to a template parameter, or alternatively, is there an idiomatic D way to achieve the concept of passing deserialized classes as class/function template parameters.

The concept is based on [DDD, CQRS and Eventsourcing](http://cqrs.nu/tutorial/cs/02-domain-logic).

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{   
    auto aggregate = new UserAggregate();
    auto command = new CreateUser();

    // in a command bus, aggregates are loaded based on the aggregate type, then commands and events are applied.
    aggregate.handle(command);

    // NOTE typecast cannot be used as events will be loaded from an event stream and deserialized - only the 
    // class name (fully qualified module path) is known at runtime.
    auto userCreated = Object.factory("app.UserCreated");
    // .... deserialization of event ....
    aggregate.apply(userCreated);  // <-- compile error - type not specific enough and casting is not possible

}

// interfaces

interface IHandleCommand(TCommand : ICommand)
{
    void handle(TCommand command);
}

interface IApplyEvent(TEvent : IEvent)
{
    void apply(TEvent event);
}

interface ICommand
{
    // ....
}

interface IEvent
{
    // ....
}


// Implementation

class UserAggregate : 
    IHandleCommand!CreateUser,
    IHandleCommand!ChangeUserStatus,
    IApplyEvent!UserCreated,
    IApplyEvent!UserStatusChanged
{
    void handle(CreateUser createUser)
    {
        writeln("createUser...");
    }

    void handle(ChangeUserStatus changeUserStatus)
    {
        writeln("changeUserStatus...");
    }

    void apply(UserCreated userCreated)
    {
        writeln("userCreated...");
    }

    void apply(UserStatusChanged userStatusChanged)
    {
        writeln("userStatusChange...");
    }
}

// Commands
class CreateUser : ICommand
{
    // ....
}

class ChangeUserStatus : ICommand
{
    // ....
}

// Events
class UserCreated : IEvent
{   
    // .... 
}

class UserStatusChanged : IEvent
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Please use [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)s. Noone cares how many interfaces you have, and it distracts from the actual problem.

Comment: Did you try to change `void apply(UserCreated userCreated)` to `void apply(IEvent userCreated)` ?

Comment: @DejanLekic How would you handle different event types in if you only use one interface type to identity the event in an aggregate?

Comment: We use the super-type anyway, right? Every other event type is of IEvent type...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use runtime values as template parameters. But you have options:

1. Cast it to IEvent and let the event initiate `apply` with an overloaded function. ([Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern))

   ```
   class UserCreated : IEvent
   {   
       override void apply(Aggregate aggregate){
           aggregate.apply(this);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use runtime type information to dispatch the event accordingly.

   ```
   void dispatch(Object event){
       if(auto casted = cast(UserCreated)event){
           apply(casted);
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: #1 Implies implementing an apply method in every IEvent instance to indirectly `bind` an aggregate type? #2 direct casting is not possible as types will be introduced which is not known to the command bus implementation. #2 could be handled with [string mixins](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial/blob/master/D-templates-tutorial.md#string-mixins)

Comment: #1 yes, #2 mixins only work with CTE strings, so you need to let UserAggregate know all types it needs to handle at compile time. A type list would be better than strings, though. Your question does not show how you would handle unknown types anyway, UserAggregate seems to know all of them.

Comment: For #2 btw, you can just do the cast and check for null: `if(auto casted = cast(UserCreated) event) apply(casted);` which is a bit nicer imo.